# Adding xml nodes from one xml file into another with powershell into a specific existing node in File 2

Tags: xml, powershell, web-config, addition

I want to add existing XML nodes from one file into another XML file by using **PowerShell**.
(Edit the Web.config from some webservices).
I tried many ways but I don`t get it running, any help would be appreciated!

**My File1 contains some code like:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<services>
  <service name="MyService.HelloWorld">
    <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0" bindingNamespace="http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld/" contract="MyService.HelloWorld" />
  </service>
  <service name="MyService.HelloMars">
    <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0" bindingNamespace="http://tempuri.org/HelloMars/" contract="MyService.HelloMars" />
  </service>
  .........
```

Now I want to add all the services into another xml file (the Web.config) and there into a specific node.

**My File2 contains some code like:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
 <configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings"
   type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
   <section name="MyServices.Properties.Settings"
    type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </sectionGroup>
 </configSections>
 <system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
 </system.web>
 <system.serviceModel>

  ............ (some more code)
      
  <diagnostics>
   <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true"       logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
    maxMessagesToLog="2000"/>
  </diagnostics>
  <services>

  **(HERE I WANT TO ADD MY SERVICES!)**
   
  </services>
```

**I also need to modify the imported services, by adding them an extra parameter (Endpoint), so that they look like this: (adding the address parameter)**

```html
<service name="MyServices.HelloWorld">
<endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NewWsHttpBinding"   bindingNamespace="http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld/"
address="https://...../HelloWorld.svc" contract="MyServices.HelloWorld"/>
</service>
```

**I tried many ways I found on the internet, but none worked.
The last thing I tried to at least merge the files was:**

```js
$webConfig = [xml](Get-Content C:\...\Web.config)
$webConfigNode = $webConfig.configuration.system.serviceModel.services
$servicesToAdd = [xml](Get-Content C:\...\services.config)
$servicesToAddNode = $servicesToAdd.services

while ($servicesToAddNode.HasChildNodes)
{
    $cn = $servicesToAddNode.FirstChild
    $cn = $servicesToAddNode.RemoveChild($cn)
    $cn = $webConfigNode.OwnerDocument.importnode($cn)
    $webConfigNode.AppendChild($cn)
}
```

**but I get the following error message:**

```html
It is not possible to run a method for an expression which is null
+     $cn = $webConfig.OwnerDocument.importnode($cn)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

**Thanks for any help!**

Answer (score 0):

Obviously too late for you, but for anyone else, the short version is that in .NET's XML Document model, nodes *belong* to their document, so you have to ...

- FIRST call Document.ImportNode to clone a node into a new document
- THEN actually insert or append the imported node somewhere

For example, if you:

```
$Source = [xml]'<root><a><s name="one"/><s name="two"/></a></root>'
$Dest = [xml]'<root><b><s name="three"/></b></root>'
foreach($node in $Source.root.a.s) {
    $clone = $Dest.ImportNode($node, $true)
    $null = $Dest.root.b.AppendChild($clode)
}
```

Then, your `$Dest.OuterXml` will be:

```
<root><b><s name="three" /><s name="one" /><s name="two" /></b></root>
```